# Error: Access of undefined property JSON ... but it IS there

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, flashdevelop

I am developing a Flash application (Flash Player 11 as target platform) that uses the AS3 Facebook API, which in turn  uses as3corelib JSON functionality. Or at least it should do so.

However, in spite of including the [latest version](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/downloads) (.93) of the as3corelib.swc, I still get the "Error: Access of undefined property JSON". I also tried including the sources directly, to no avail.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

As I said, the *.swc is definitely included. As is the source code (all at the correct path).

**Edit:**

I have a more specific error message:

```
Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. JSON (from C:\Coding\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc(JSON, Walker)) and com.adobe.serialization.json:JSON (from C:\flash_test\lib\as3corelib.swc)) are available.
```

I know that JSON is included in AIR, but I do not target AIR, so why does it try include the airglobal.swc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that Flash Player 11 and onwards has native JSON support, so the JSON class you are including is likely colliding with the one from as3corelib. Hence the ambiguity problem.

Try removing as3corelib entirely and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. This was a problem, and also a bug in FlashDevelop that caused FD to think I wanted AIR although I specified FP 11 as target platform. After fixing both, it now works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to delete the as3corelib.swc from my project lib folder but it gives new error as com.adobe.utils.strinUtil not found

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be written as "StringUtil"? In any case, you could try downloading the sources of as3corelib and only keep the stuff that you need, like StringUtil.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the full path to the class. Example, code:

...

var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data);

...

will be

...

var jsonData:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(loader.data);
...